# Eclipse: The project was not built due to "A resource exists with a different case: '/project/bin/License.txt'."

Tags: java, eclipse, github, mainclass

I get this error under the problems tab. I downloaded a project off of github then imported it to eclipse and added the libraries to the build path. When I try to run I get the error :
    Could not find or load main class blah.blah.blah.StartupClass
I've done a ton of googling and I cant figure it out. Thanks for you help. Here is my project
http://puu.sh/dEMHk/4609006ff1.png also here is my eclipse project in a zip http://puu.sh/dEMLZ/1092da9f36.zip

Comment: could you provide your project structure and main class?